# Get conversation ID with Tweepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

Basically I want to get the `conversation_id` if the Tweet is a reply to another Tweet. So I can get the list of replies to each other to analyze.

My code:

```
class Listener(StreamingClient):

    def on_response(self, response):
        print(response)


listener = Listener(auth['bearer_token'])
listener.sample(expansions=['in_reply_to_user_id'], tweet_fields=['conversation_id'])
```

When using this, I only get the `user_id` to which it is replying, but I cannot get any type of `conversation_id`.

I have a slight feeling I am missing something essential.

Answer (score 0):

From [the relevant FAQ section about this in Tweepy's documentation](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.7.0/faq.html#why-am-i-not-getting-expansions-or-fields-data-with-api-v2-using-client):

> If you are simply printing the objects and looking at that output, the string representations of API v2 models/objects only include the default fields that are guaranteed to exist.
>
> The objects themselves still include the relevant data, which you can access as attributes or by subscription.

Comment: If it is a reply, so contains in_reply_to_user_id, is it not a conversation or is part of a conversation?

Comment: That's not directly relevant to this question. Replies make up a [conversation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/conversation-id).